# My pygame sprites get missaligned overtime

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to develop a platformer, but when I started implementing gravity and a jump mechanic the sprites of my terrain get misaligned on the y axis and I really don't know what is wrong.

My code consist of tree main classes:

- `Player`: This class has all the logic of the player.
- `Level`: This one have the logic of the level and this is probably where my error is coming from.
- `Tile`: This class generates all the tiles of the terrain and could also be part of the issue.

There is also a class named `Game` but the issue is 100% not coming from there as all this class does for now is initialize the level class.

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

# Settings
tile_size = 64
fov = 10
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = tile_size * fov

level_data = [
'                       ',
'                       ',
'                  XX   ',
'XX    XXX              ',
'XX                   XX',
'XXXX        XX         ',
'XXXX  P   XX           ',
'XX    X  XXX    XX  X  ',
'      X  XXX    XX  XX ',
'   XXXX  XXXXX  XX  XXX',
'XXXXXXX  XXXXX  XX  XXX']

# Classes
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = Level(screen)
        self.status = 'level'

    def run(self):
        if self.status == 'level':
            self.level.run()

class Level:
    def __init__(self,display_surface):
        # Basic setup
        self.setup_level()
        self.display_surface = display_surface

        # Movement
        self.x_shift = 0
        self.y_shift = 0

    def setup_level(self):
        self.tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
        for row_index,row in enumerate(level_data):
            for col_index,col in enumerate(row):
                x = col_index * tile_size
                y = (row_index * tile_size) - ((len(level_data) - fov) * tile_size)
                if col == 'X':
                    tile = Tile((x,y))
                    self.tiles.add(tile)
                if col == 'P':
                    player = Player((x,y))
                    self.player.add(player)

    def apply_gravity(self):
        player = self.player.sprite
        self.y_shift = player.direction.y

    def run(self):
        # Tiles
        self.tiles.update(self.x_shift,self.y_shift)
        self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)

        # Player
        self.player.update()
        self.apply_gravity()
        self.player.draw(self.display_surface)

class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((tile_size,tile_size))
        self.image.fill('grey')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)

    def update(self,x_shift,y_shift):
        self.rect.x += x_shift
        self.rect.y -= y_shift

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        super().__init__()
        # Image
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32,64))
        self.image.fill('red')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)

        # Movement
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0,0)
        self.gravity = 0.8

    def get_inputs(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.direction.y = -20

    def apply_gravity(self):
        self.direction.y += self.gravity

    def update(self):
        self.get_inputs()
        self.apply_gravity()

# Game setup
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game = Game()

# Main
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    
    screen.fill('black')
    game.run()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem and is related to [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the coordinates gets lost when the new offset is added to the position of the *Rect* object. If this is done every frame, the position error will accumulate over time.

> ```py
> self.rect.x += x_shift
> self.rect.y -= y_shift
> ```

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location (e.g. `.topleft`) of the rectangle:

```py
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((tile_size,tile_size))
        self.image.fill('grey')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        self.x = self.rect.x
        self.y = self.rect.y

    def update(self,x_shift,y_shift):
        self.x += x_shift
        self.y -= y_shift
        self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```